# How flexible are CouchDB MapReduce views?

Tags: ibm-cloud, couchdb, cloudant

If I have a Cloudant MapReduce view with year/month/day as the key array, can I query the dataset just by month or just by day?

Answer (score 2):

No. You can query by y/m/d or by y/m or by y.
In other words, you are allowed to omit fields, but you cannot have gaps, so you have to start omitting from the right.

Examples:

- Querying by y/m/d -- `key=[2022,5,20]` finds everything for one day
- Querying by y/m -- `startkey=[2022,1]&endkey=[2022,2]` finds everything in January
- Querying by y -- `startkey=[2021]&endkey=[2022]` finds everything in 2021